# Removing the individual row in child schema inside the array of parent mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to remove the child schema's row based on certain field and schema is inside the array of parent schema. i have tried with below code but failed.can any one resolve this
//code details
use_list is parent schema in which its array field called frr_list has array element as schemas . and i want to remove individual row of that child schema based on fren_id.
//

```js
//main parent schema
var user_list = new Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user_reg'
  },
  fren_list: [fren_list],
  block_list: [fren_block_list],
  frr_list: [fern_req_recieved_list], //asking about this array 
  frs_list: [fern_req_sent_list],
});


//child schema
var fern_req_recieved_list = new Schema({ //fren req list
  fren_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user_reg'
  },
  fren_name: String,
  dt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: "pending"
  } //pending, rejected,accepted

});


User.list.findOne({ //parent document
  user_id: currentUserId
}, function(err, user) {
  ///below is child inside the array field and is schema
  user.frr_list.findOneAndRemove({
    fren_id: requestedUserId
  }, function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
      callback(null, false);
    } else {
      callback(null, true);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you can delete the individual items of frr_list array like this:

I assume that you will be deleting the individual items of frr_list by frr_id (which is _id which is generated by mongoose)

User.update({ _id: userListId,
                user_id:currentUserId
                //filter record by userListId and currentUserId
            },

{ //now pull the required row from the array based on _id of array
        $pull: { frr_list: { _id: frr_id } } },
        function(err,result){
            if(result.ok==1 && result.nModified==1 && result.n==1)
                //successfully deleted
            else if(result.ok==1 && result.nModified==0 && result.n==0)
               //no record exist
            else
               //something goes wrong
        });

Comment: yes $pull will do the work as it is the operator for pulling the array items of embedded array  :P